# Can't change background color of CheckBox view twice - Android

Tags: android, user-interface, view, background

I try to change **CheckBox** background after user change its state to **Checked**. Code below doesn't work quite well. If i click unchecked checkbox its changes state and color to blue, when i click it again and uncheck, color stays blue instead changing to red. I did introduced call of **invalidate()** with no sucess. I confirmed that method recievies clicks and correctly sees checked status, but **if statement** i've made seems to work only once.

**XML**

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkLargeIcons"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:onClick="handleCheckBoxClick" />
```

**Code**

```
public void handleCheckBoxClick(View view) {
    CheckBox tmpChkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(view.getId());
    if(tmpChkBox.isChecked())
    {
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(color.blue);
    }
    else
    {
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(color.red);
    }

    System.out.println(view.getId() + " " + tmpChkBox.isChecked());

    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.chkLargeIcons:
        ...     
    break;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What should i change in my code to make it work as i want?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: @JustinJasmann I have multiple checkboxes with for which i specified same "OnClick" method, this code is inside this method, and as System.out.println outputs stuff as it should be, visual state of checkbox stays the same after one or two clicks

Comment: Could you post more of your code to show where you are tieing in this listener?

Comment: @JustinJasmann done, though i don't know how it is relevant while system.out.println prints all interactions with checkboxes correctly

Comment: I'm just trying to reproduce it myself. The if/else works fine for me. What are you doing in your switch/case?

Comment: @JustinJasmann just some method calls, but even if i cutout switch it still doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, very odd. I actually think jimmithy's answer below is the more correct way to do it, as opposed to overriding the onClick. Regardless, your method works for me.

Comment: The last think I can think, is that maybe one of your method calls in the switch/case is causing a large amount of lag, thus not exiting the method to actually change the background colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some explanation of one unclear aspect

Thing is that example colors mentioned in my code might be misleading if someone assume that i use android **Color** class. While i was using my versions of colors **red** and **blue** stored in **color.xml** and thats why I stated them in code as ***color.red*** instead of ***Color.RED***.

So my code as same as listener code in other answer, both are valid if you assume that color is taken from android class.

Source of my problem is some strange glitch, or not known by me android behaviour that causes following code work faulty.

```
public void handleCheckBoxClick(View view) {
    CheckBox tmpChkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(view.getId());
    if(tmpChkBox.isChecked())
    {
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(color.blue);
    }
    else
    {
        tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(color.red);
    }
}
```

**Precisely lines like this one**

```
    tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor([ColorFromResources]);
```

While execution of code gave me just one occurence of color change, then it just stayed like that, completly unresponsive. That one change was largely misleading and got me stuck on this problem long time, and even made me leave it for later fixing.
After some more research i figured that **following change in code fixes my issue:**

```
   tmpChkBox.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor([ColorFromResources]));
```

Now all works like a charm. But I'm still puzzled why does call of color from resources works without **getResources().getColor(...)**. Hopefully that answer will help someone as strangely stuck as me.

Answer (score 2):

For it to change when checked you need to attach an OnCheckChangedListener. Then place the above code inside that.

```
CheckBox tmpChkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(view.getId());
tmpChkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else { 
            buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: It doesnt work in my case, the difference is, it changes color to blue after check and uncheck, and stop working. Other concern - is it good practice to set many times same listener for one obejct, code of my method handles multiple checkboxes and distinct them by id.