# CheckBox with Background color as Pink

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I want the check box with background colour pink and on checked the colour should be white. How to do this in a list view ???

I want something like this shown below !!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmnd6.jpg

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have look at this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819096/cant-change-background-color-of-checkbox-view-twice-android)

Comment: You can refer this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Default Color of Android CheckBox Check Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302428/changing-default-color-of-android-checkbox-check-mark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `selector`

Sample: create /res/drawable/checkbox_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked" android:state_checked="true"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/default"></item>

</selector>
```

and then apply to CheckBox

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_bg" />
```

Comment: this is the simplest way to do..nice